# Prevent Online Search of Get-Help in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to prevent `Get-Help` from searching online for help? I recently updated my entire help system so I'm fairly certain it's as complete as can be: nevertheless `Get-Help` on certain commands seems to search the web each time and find nothing which is costing me performance (my app is using get-help to reflect how Cmdlets can be used).

[image]

`Get-Help java` really goes crazy searching:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't search online unless you are using the flag '-Online' (which is disabled in remote sessions).

From MSDN: `Get-Help` *first looks for help files in the locale set for Windows, then in the parent locale, such as "pt" for "pt-BR", and then in a fallback locale.*

Try using `Update-Help` again as well, it may update the locale set for Windows.

Comment: Ditto on the -Online thing. You can use a scheduled task, to do this daily, weekly, etc... in the background and run hidden so you don't have to worry about it, ever seeing it. Help is / can be updated regularly, and if you clock this, you won't have the latest.

Comment: I definitely am not using `-Online` with `Get-Help` and, as my screenshot shows, it appears to be searching online... and taking some time (20s) doing so.

Comment: Type in "get-help java" and see what it does: on my system is searches for minutes...